Exception: <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require'
Exception: <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)
    from <internal:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

I try to use firebase in my project. When I run the commond
flutterfire configure --project=fir-demo-54e7c

it responds with the Exception.

Apparently xcodeproj gem is not installed

It looks like the gem is not installed. Try installing it by:
gem install xcodeproj
Then check if it comes up in
gem list
Also install xcode if not already installed
xcode-select --install
